# Rspec testing, ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

I'm having trouble running a test using `rspec`. In my `book.rb` file the code block passes all the tests given to it for capitalizing words in the titles of books ("to kill a mockingbird", "inferno"). However, when I run rake from the terminal I am repeatedly getting the error message

```
"Failure/Error: @book.title.should == "Inferno"
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)".
```

I've tried changing the params and removing the title method but nothing works, I still get the error message even though the program capitalizes the titles as it should. Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title, :littlewords

  def initialize
    @littlewords = ["the", "a", "an", "and", "of", "in"]
  end

  def title
    @title 
  end

  def title(lit)
    @title = ''
    books = lit.split
    books.each do |title|
      title.capitalize! unless (littlewords.to_s).include?(title)
    end

    books[0] = books[0].upcase
    books.first.capitalize!
    books.join(' ')
  end
end

s = Book.new
puts s.title("to kill a mockingbird")
puts s.title("inferno")
```

Comment: Your problem is that the second `title` method, which takes a parameter, is overwriting your first `title` method. I think you want `def title=(lit)` and then call it with `s.title = "to kill a mockingbird"` Also, the first `title` isn't needed since you have it set as `attr_accessor`

Answer (score 0):

In other languages, you can have multiple methods that are named the same but take in different parameters. In those languages, they are actually two different methods.

Ruby is not that way.

When you define your second method, `title`, you are actually writing over the first method `title`. So, instead of two methods where one takes an argument and one doesn't, you have one method which takes an argument.

So, when you call `@book.title.should`, it is calling that second method that is expecting an argument.

First off, you don't need the first method `title` since you set it up in the beginning with `attr_accessor`. You get that method for free.

So, when you use:

```
attr_accessor :title
```

You get:

```
def title
  @title
end

def title=(value)
  @title = value
end
```

So, what you want to do is overwrite that second method.

```
attr_reader :title

def title=(lit)
  books = lit.split
  books.each do |title|
    title.capitalize! unless (littlewords.to_s).include?(title)
  end

  books[0] = books[0].upcase
  books.first.capitalize!
  @title = books.join(' ')
end
```

So you can set the titles as such:

```
s = Book.new
puts s.title = "to kill a mockingbird" #=> "To Kill a Mockingbird"
puts s.title = "inferno" #=> "Inferno"
```

This will also enable your test `@book.title.should` to work as expected.